# How do I turn off the hot water so I can fix a leaking hot tap

Tags: faucet

My laundry hot water tap is dripping. I want to change the washer inside the tap but I'm unsure how to turn off the hot water.

Comment: What part of the world are you in?  Single family home or is it an apartment or condo type unit?

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world, there will be an isolating valve (see below) under the sink which you just turn.
[image: inline isolating valve from Screwfix website]

Given you are asking the question, there probably isn't.

In that case you need to follow the pipework back until you find a valve.  Places to look:

1. If you have a hot water tank, there may be a valve to prevent any water coming out of it.  If there is, you can use that.
2. (If you have a hot water tank, and have to use any of the following valves, you may have to drain the hot water tank).  Check if there is a valve to stop water flowing *in* to the hot water tank.
3. Check if there is a valve before or after the boiler.
4. If you have a cold water tank, there may be a valve to stop water coming out of it.
5. Ultimately, you may have to turn off all water to the house (and if you have a cold water tank, you will have to drain it).  You *do* know where the main water stop-cock is don't you?  If not, now is a *really* good time to find it!  (Not when there is water pouring through a ceiling.)

Depending on how far back you have to go in order to cut off the water, you might want to consider taking this opportunity to add some additional isolating valves - it's very easy.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the system and who installed it.

On a basic system, then you need to turn off the incoming water supply to the dwelling and that stops the supply to everything, then you can work on the laundry tap, water may still come out due to air getting in and gravity.

However, some systems will have an isolator prior to the tank so that the tank can be isolated leaving other things working.

Other systems will have an isolator before each tap and you can just use that - makes life very easy but not always done.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you do not have to change the "washer" in the cut-off valve. It could be that all you have to do is tighten the bonnet nut on this valve. We need to know exactly where it is leaking to tell you what to do. If it is leaking around the stem with the valve open as it would normally be if the washer was connected with a supply hose, it may be that you do not have to shut off the water to the house, but simply have to tighten a so called bonnet nut around the stem.

But if the valve is old, then it is possible that the valve needs to be disassembled for repair or even replaced with a new valve.

To open up for repair or to remove to replace *any* of the hot water cut-off valves, including the hot for the clothes washer, you must normally turn off the water supply valve on the input of the water heater. As long as you are working on the valve the entire house will be without any hot water. The exception to this is that some modern plumbing systems have a manifold or manifolds which allow shutting off the water selectively to certain parts of the house.

Depending on how your house is constructed this valve will be in the basement or in a box in the ground outside next to the house  or at the water meter. In my area of Dallas, Texas everyone uses the cut-off valve on the city side of the water meter in a box in the ground next to the street. The city of Dallas is aware that their valves are being used for this purpose and does not actively object.

As per the local plumbing code in original construction all houses here have a set of valves in a box in the ground next to the foundation, but the type of valve used in the 1970s (a so called "gate" valve) would corrode and become inoperable in 10 years or less. The ball valves used nowadays last much longer, maybe indefinitely.